# Ember.JS loading sub-state issue

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am using Ember-cli and would like to show loading spinner when model is loading. I create a application loading template and it works fine, but only when ember debugger is opened.

Here is [Video with this bug](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_qgqxcteCpjMVVTeWhkdDJiRkE/view?usp=sharing). Did have anyone this problem before?

#### UPD. Answer from this [Question](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-loading-sub-state-issue-solved/7852/4?u=kolybasov)

You need explicitly create loading route for templates where your global loading template is not working.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe what is pods?

Comment: Nevermind. Pods are part of the new optional file structure being introduced to ember-cli. You're probably not using it.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I just read about pods and you are right, I don't use it.